# How to get specific items using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm using this code to select a URL in `div` tag

```
 Elements mElements = doc.select("a[class^=titr]");
 Element linkElement = mElements.select("a").first();
 linkElement.attr("href");
```

but in this cod I just can see first item Because the method is `first();`

how can I specific that I want to select for example item 0 to 20 instead of first ??

Comment: select returns an `Elements`, which is `Iterable`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select specific items in foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862531/select-specific-items-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Are you going to add my answer as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `mElements` is returned as a `List<Element>` - try `mElements.get(0)` for each one; for all of them iterated:

```
    print("\nElements: (%d)", mElements.size());
    for (Element link : mElements) {
        print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
    }
```

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html

This is however probably not recommended, since arrays change over time; perhaps you want a better selector method.
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax