# Select specific items in foreach loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach, jsoup

I have this code to getting some tags:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
String result = inputestreamToString(stream);
String html = result;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements mElements = doc.select("div[class^=news-item]");

for (Element e: mElements) 
{
    title = e.text();
    jobtitle.add(title);

    StructNote note = new StructNote();
    note.title = title;
    Notes.add(note);

}
```

I have 100 divs and with this loop I can get all of them. But I want to get only 20 items.

Comment: then i would have an int count which increments for each iteration. when `count = 20`, *break* out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Iterables#limit](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
for (Element e : Iterables.limit(mElements, 20)) 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I can't use Iterables.limit Eclipse said Iterables cannot be resolved

Comment: Add the Guava [JAR](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar) to the classpath of your Eclipse Java project.

Answer (score 1):

[JSOUP - Elements API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) provides you the sublist functionality to extract the sublist from the Elements.

You can use

```
 List<Element> subLists = mElements.subList(0,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select first 20 elements then you can :

```
List<String> subItems = new ArrayList<String>(jobtitle.subList(0, 19));
List<StructNote> subItems = new ArrayList<StructNote>(Notes.subList(0, 19));
```